# Backbone.js destroying a subset of a Collection

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, model-view-controller, frontend

Using Backbone.js as a front-end framework for my Rails app. In terms of Rails models I have a Publication model and an Article model. Each publication is associated with many articles and each article only belongs to one publication. When the user decides to delete a publication I want all the associated articles also deleted. When I say deleted I mean removed from the database.

The following code works in terms of deleting the specified Publication from the database but does not work for deleting the associated articles:

```
  // destroys the proper publication but still needs to update the view
  delete_publication: function(id){
    var publication = new SimpleGoogleReader.Models.Publication({id: id});
    publication.fetch({
      success: function(x){
      }
    });
    publication.destroy();

    var articles = new SimpleGoogleReader.Collections.Articles();
    articles.fetch({
      data: {publication_id: id},
      success: function(x){
      }
    });
    articles.destroy();
  }

});
```

I also tried moving the articles.destroy() line inside the success function but that did not work either. I could be wrong but I think by the time I call the .destroy() function on articles I am no longer working with a Collection object. Am I going about this wrong? I want a Collection object just not containing every Model, only the specified ones.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to delete the articles first :

```
// destroys the proper publication but still needs to update the view
  delete_publication: function(id){

    var articles = new SimpleGoogleReader.Collections.Articles();
    articles.fetch({
      data: {publication_id: id},
      success: function(x){
      }
    });
    articles.reset(); // empty the collection
    articles.sync(); // persist the state of the collection to the server

    var publication = new SimpleGoogleReader.Models.Publication({id: id});
    publication.fetch({
      success: function(x){
      }
    });
    publication.destroy();
  }

});
```

Comment: I have not tried that. Question: I can delete the articles from the Collection, but then how do I update the database to reflect that change?

Comment: Have not gotten to it yet. Will answer once I revisit. Soon